# Cycle decomposition for elements of order 2 in $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

I'm asked to write out the cycle decomposition of each element of order 2 in $S_4$. However, from my understanding, a cycle decomposition is the product of disjoint cycles. But the elements in $S_4$ of order 2 are already products of disjoint cycles. For example,

How do I simplify (1 2) or (1 2)(3 4)?

Isn't the only way to write (1 2) as a product (1 2)=(1 2)(1 2)? Which is not disjoint and hence not a cycle decomposition? And isn't (1 2)(3 4) already a cycle decomposition?

Comment: (12)(34) is just one way of representing that permutation. Fundamentally, the permutation is the function that sends 1 -> 2, 2->1, 3-> 4, 4->3. The question is really asking for the obvious thing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598644/cycle-decompositions-of-s-4/1598658, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311680/finding-the-number-of-elements-of-order-two-in-the-symmetric-group-s-4/311684

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the question is looking for you to identify the ones which are of order 2.  It's more of an identification problem and not a decomposition problem.